# SwiftUI: Global Binding Date Variable

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a Global Binding Date that I can use across multiple areas of my App.

Essentially, I want to allow the use to change 'todays date' to any future date and update the rest of my app accordingly.

I've tried creating a GlobalVariables class in a Swift file, but getting a bit lost as to how to create the variable correctly (the below code errors)

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject {
    
    @Binding var myDate: Date = Date()
    
}
```

I want to then use a DatePicker in another View to update the myDate variable, which will then update the other bits of my App.

Thanks

Comment: `@Binding` is a two-way connection, it cannot be initialized. it just creates a bridge between a source of truth and something that modifies it. Also, most SwiftUI wrappers inherit [DynamicProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty) therefore they can only be declared in a SwiftUI `View` because they depend on the `body`. The only exception so far seems `@Published` for an `ObservableObject`. You should look at [Managing Model Data in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) and use an `EnvironmentObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use @Published property wrapper. This way it will publish any changes and update the UI accordingly.

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject {

    @Published var myDate = Date()

}
```

You also need to inject the same instance of your GlobalVariables in order to sync all views. You can use environment object or dependency injection with other methods.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject globalVariables = GlobalVariables()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FirstView()
                .environmentObject(globalVariables)

            SecondView()
                .environmentObject(globalVariables)
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalVariables: GlobalVariables
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $globalVariables.myDate)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalVariables: GlobalVariables
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $globalVariables.myDate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that works to a degree... but when I try and use that within my DatePicker, I'm getting an "Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'Binding<Date>" error?

Comment: You need to use as DatePicker("My Picker", selection: $globalVariables.myDate). "$" symbol is needed for binding.

Comment: Ah amazing (annoyingly simple!) when I do this it doesn't seem to be updating across my other Views? I've added it into the same view as the DataPicker and it updates instantly, should I be doing something in the other Views to refresh the data?

Comment: I added a way to sync both views using Environment Object. You should use environment object in a way that is appropriate to your view structure.

Comment: Ah amazing! Been trying to figure this out for days, thank you! (p.s. you need to add Var onto your @EnvironmentObject examples for it to work :)

Comment: Its good except but @StateObject will cause the MainView's body to needlessly run every time the object changes and there is no need to tie the objects lifetime to this view. You could avoid this by doing it the old way,  declare it outside of the struct or as a singleton if need access in other swift files.

Comment: I agree. Injecting the dependency using Resolver etc. would definitely be my choice. However, this question is not about that complex subject.